# What does Ctrl+e & Ctrl+y do in insert mode of Vim? I have accidentally found out a funny cmd which I don't know what's the application

Tags: insert-mode

In normal mode:

```
Ctrl+y          Scrolling screen dw with the cursor staying on the same line 
Ctrl+e          Scrolling screen up with the cursor staying on the same line
```

However in insert/edit mode:
<kbd>Ctrl e</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl y</kbd> do funny stuff.

e.g. with <kbd>Ctrl e</kbd> (in insert mode):

I put my cursor in front of `Ctrl+y` in edit mode and pressed <kbd>Ctrl e</kbd> 20 times, this is the outcome (as below), it actually duplicating the line under cursor character by character and right shift the existing line:

```
Ctrl+e          ScroCtrl+y       Scrolling screen dw with the cursor staying on the same line 
Ctrl+e          Scrolling screen up with the cursor staying on the same line
```

e.g. 2 with <kbd>Ctrl y</kbd> (in insert mode):
I put my cursor in front of `Ctrl+e` in edit mode and pressed <kbd>Ctrl y</kbd> 30 times, this is the outcome (as below), it actually duplicating the line above the cursor character by character and right shift the existing line:

```
Ctrl+y          Scrolling screen dw with the cursor staying on the same line 
Ctrl+y          Scrolling screeCtrl+e          Scrolling screen up with the cursor staying on the same line
```

What is the application of this <kbd>Ctrl e</kbd> amd <kbd>Ctrl y</kbd> in edit mode anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have guessed correctly.

Here is what the documentation is saying (`:help i_CTRL-e`):

```
CTRL-E  Insert the character which is below the cursor.

CTRL-Y  Insert the character which is above the cursor.
        Note that for CTRL-E and CTRL-Y 'textwidth' is not used, to be
        able to copy characters from a long line.
```

It is a functionality also present in the shell command line before cut and past was available it can save you writing variation of the same lines.

I don't use it. A number of people chose to remap <kbd>Ctrl e</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl y</kbd> in insert mode. These days a number of people consider these two commands as not very helpful.

Comment: And a number of people, me included, use them very often.

Comment: Interesting. In which context? Could you give us an example? I'm curious too.

Comment: In insert mode, for the exact purpose they are designed for. When code is repetitive and vertically aligned, which happens pretty often, there are plenty of occasions where pressing `<C-y>` 2-3 times is more efficient or less mentally taxing than other approaches. Typically, completion is usually useful for keywords but less so for operators and such.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I'll pay more attention to the opportunities :-)

Comment: I still can't get what @romaini said... can't get the picture.  sigh! something is hard to explain/ understand by text form of explaination.

Comment: why not use yank and paste ?

Comment: I would indeed do that but maybe you like not to leave insert  mode :-)

Comment: ya.. but to copy the vertical repetitive code onto a new line be it above or beneath cursor by pressing ctrl-e or ctrl-y multiple time (depend on how many characters want to copy).. isn't that is not efficient ?